# How to refresh part of page every 1min?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, refresh, setinterval, document-ready

I want to refresh my specific div partition on page at every 1min. How can I do that?
Here my test structure:

```
<div id="test">
   //something inside model items like @Model.TotalUpDeviceCount.ToString()
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                refresh();
            }, 60000);
        });

        function refresh() {
            $('#test').modal.refresh();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a little more to it than your suggested code.

you want to show the updated data coming from your controller which requires a complete page refresh. 
you can however retrieve the data from an api controller and update the div with polling.

```
setTimeout($.get("....", function(data) {
   $("your div").html(data)
});, 1500)
```

Comment: Yes, I wanna get index data from home controller.
Moreover, I added your advice like that:
```
$(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout($.get("Home/Index", function (data) {
                $("#test").html(data)
            }), 60000);
        });
```
but didnt worked :/

Comment: you need to add an api controller.